# SNMP MIB for finding if Router is busy

Tags: linux, snmp, cisco, mib

I want to be able to use snmpget on a cisco router to find out if it is busy or not by seeing how many packets it is handling. I want to do this so I can plan out a good time to use that router when it is not busy. I have tried
 `snmpget -v1 -c public -r 0 ip address 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.2.1.1.7`
which is the oid for "Five minute exponentially-decayed moving 
average of input packets per second". I have also tried the oid 1.3.6.1.2.1.7526.2.1.1 but I keep getting the error message "There is no such variable name in this MIB". I was having trouble trying to find someone who was trying to do the same on the internet. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What objects/variables exist in an SNMP enabled device is determined by its vendor. Thus, right now you should contact Cisco support instead of anyone else to learn more about the model you use, and then learn if there is a specific way to get the information you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many system administrators use a free tool such as [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/), [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), [Cricket](http://cricket.sourceforge.net/), or [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) to SNMP poll and graph the traffic flowing through their routers. All these tools should be able to read the standard [IF-MIB](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/mibs/interfaces.html) - in particular the objects `ifInOctets` and `ifOutOctets`.